# Can't login as replication user

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

```
mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE,FILE ON *.*
    -> TO 'repl'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password123';

mysql -u repl -p'password123'

Access denied for user 'repl'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Is a mysql user with replication privilege only, not allowed to login?

I've tried resetting the password, I get the same result.

Comment: Did you execute the `flush privileges` command on mysql prompt after granting the permissions?

Comment: Yes, actually, I'm already running replication using that user.

Comment: The replication user should be allowed to login as any other user. I can notice that `repl` is created on `localhost`. Usually, you should create it on `other_ip_host`. Is this for testing only?

Comment: You're right Khaled, that was it. Sorry for the misinformation. I was trying to simplify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Khaled mentioned in the comments, replication users are generally created on the remote server. I was creating it like this, the question is incorrect:

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE,FILE ON *.*
-> TO 'repl'@'remoteip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password123';
```

So if you have issues logging in as a replication user, make sure you're logging in from the remote server.